# R: sample equal Ns, within groups

Tags: r, tidyverse, sampling

I have a data set, in which observations are divided into groups and subgroups, and into types.
Here's an example of such data:

```
data <- data.frame(group    = sample(c(1:30),    10000, replace = TRUE),
                   subgroup = sample(c(1:100),   10000, replace = TRUE),
                   type    = sample(c("A", "B"), 10000, replace = TRUE),
                   value   = sample(c(1:100),    10000, replace = TRUE))
```

I need to sample equal Ns of each type, within each combination of group and subgroup.

In this example, as well as in the actual data, many combinations of group+subgroup+type are empty. Such combinations for which N = 0 are to be dropped.

My solution is as follows:

---

First, I find the N to be sampled for each group & subgroup. I count how many As and Bs are within each combination and choose the smaller number:

```
library(tidyverse)

n_to_sample <- data %>%
  group_by(group, subgroup, type) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("group", "subgroup"),
              names_from =  "type",
              values_from = "n") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(lowestN = min(A, B)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(lowestN)) %>%
  select (group, subgroup, lowestN)
```

Second, I sample observations, according to the Ns counted earlier:

```
data_sampled <- data %>%
  left_join(n_to_sample, by = c("group", "subgroup")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(lowestN)) %>%
  arrange(group, type) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(sample(which(type == "A"), mean(lowestN)),
                             sample(which(type == "B"), mean(lowestN))),
         .by = c("group", "subgroup"))
```

To verify the procedure, I check that how many observations are left whithin each combination  of group+subgroup+type:

```
data %>%
  count(group, type, subgroup) %>%
  arrange(group, subgroup, type) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("group", "subgroup"),
              names_from =  "type",
              values_from = "n")
```

However, this check results in many NAs in the count variables. So my solution was not successful.
Where did I go wrong?
What can I do to correct it?

(NOTE: I'm not so interested in efficiency, which could probably be better. I just want it to work properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach which first computes the `lowestN` per group, subgroup and type, then splits the data by these variables, draws the sample and binds by row.

Note: I stripped down your example data to make it more minimal.

```r
set.seed(1)

n <- 20
data <- data.frame(
  group = sample(c(1:2), n, replace = TRUE),
  subgroup = sample(c(1:2), n, replace = TRUE),
  type = sample(c("A", "B"), n, replace = TRUE),
  value = sample(c(1:100), n, replace = TRUE)
)

library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data |>
  add_count(group, subgroup, type, name = "lowestN") |>
  mutate(
    lowestN = if (length(unique(type)) == 2) min(lowestN) else NA,
    .by = c(group, subgroup)
  ) |>
  filter(!is.na(lowestN)) |> 
  split(~ group + subgroup + type, drop = TRUE) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    x[sample(nrow(x), size = unique(x$lowestN)), ]
  }) |>
  bind_rows() |> 
  arrange(group, subgroup, type)
#>    group subgroup type value lowestN
#> 1      1        1    A     6       2
#> 2      1        1    A    70       2
#> 3      1        1    B    70       2
#> 4      1        1    B    51       2
#> 5      1        2    A    40       2
#> 6      1        2    A    65       2
#> 7      1        2    B     2       2
#> 8      1        2    B    87       2
#> 9      2        1    A    18       2
#> 10     2        1    A    75       2
#> 11     2        1    B    32       2
#> 12     2        1    B    42       2
#> 13     2        2    A    22       1
#> 14     2        2    B    81       1
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. Thanks!